# Is the supremum test of cumulative martingales residuals OK to assess proportional hazards of both groups and covariates?

Tags: sas, proportional-hazards

Is the supremum test of cumulative martingales residuals (as implemented by [assess](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_phreg_sect007.htm) in SAS `PROC PHREG`, and other software) OK for testing PH of both continuous covariates and of group?

Comment: If you remove the SAS information and just focus on your question in the last paragraph this would, I think, be on-topic here.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.